How to maximize winning in this 3-card game?
Assume you're playing a game where each round you need to pick one of the three cards:
[1] [2] [3]

One of them is Lose, two others — Win. Rounds are independent, the cards shuffled every time. So, the Lose probability is $\frac{1}{3}$, the Win probability is $\frac{2}{3}$, every time.
The game master does not show you all the cards when you pick one. They only show you the card you pick. E.g. for the example above, if you pick [2] and it's a Lose card, you see:
[1] [L] [3]

Same if you pick [3] and it's a Win card:
[1] [2] [W]

How to pick a card to maximize the number of rounds where you get a Win card? Should you pick them randomly? Or is it okay to always pick the same?
Does the knowledge of the previous round outcome determine the next round pick?

After each round, does the game master shuffle the cards uniformly, such that the probability that the cards are in a specific order is equivalent to the probability that the cards are in any other order? If not, then you can gain some information after each round to estimate the distribution of the permutations over time.

If the rounds are independent and shuffled every time there doesn't seem to be an overarching strategy, it's just a $2/3$ guess every time. Unless I missed something there is no information gained.

@mhdadk, the game master shuffles the cards uniformly, yes.

@PBulls, I may sound a bit silly, but how to prove that there is no strategy to win here?

There's little to show, because that's an immediate consequence of the assumptions "Rounds are independent, the cards shuffled every time."

I'm not sure if you are doing this as part of a problem for a class or not, but if you are, I'm wondering if you have the details right?  This looks like it's set up a little like the classic Monte Hall problem, only in that scenario, two cards would be losers and one a winner.  You then pick a card and the host/conductor of the game shows you one of the losing cards.  You are then given a choice of whether to keep your choice or switch to the remaining, different, unseen card, and it's to your advantage to switch in this scenario.

@StatsStudent, nope, I'm too old for the classes already  :-) I'm doing it because my wife was playing a game with a mini game inside, which was a card game similar to the one I described here. I thought that it may be similar to Monte Hall, and maybe there is a trick, but I'm too dumb with probabilities, that's why I decided to ask. But there is no other details, so it probably has nothing to do with the MH problem :-)

@Igor Adamenko, hahah.  You're never to old for classes, in my humble opinion.  But fair enough.  It just seemed to sound a bit like the classic Monte Hall problem and I just wanted to make sure you had the details of the question right.
By the way, you can prove the results to yourself if you wanted and you know how to program.  It would be very easy to whip up a little program yourself to help you better understand the probabilities and results.

@StatsStudent, actually, that exactly what I did :D I posted the question and then was like “Wait, I can simulate all the cases easily”. Wrote a simple program which showed me that the probability does not change no matter what. But I thought there might be a formal solution and decided not to remove the question :-)

Yes, I think it's good that you left the question.  There is, in some sense a formal solution, but there's just not too much to it.

Consider this mathematical formulation of the game.

In each iteration $n=1,2,3,\ldots,$ a strategy is a choice of a card that depends (possibly randomly!) on the choices and outcomes in all previous games $i=1, 2, \ldots, n-1.$

The shuffle, if it's uniform and independent of the strategy (as assumed), therefore causes the strategy to be a winner with probability $1/3$ (by the very meanings of "uniform" and "independent").


This mathematically proves that all strategies have the same probability of winning at each iteration and therefore any strategy you pick will be the best one possible--as well as the worst one possible!  Moreover, no matter how large (or small) $n$ might be, knowledge of the preceding results provides no advantage whatsoever.

This is the basis for using randomization in sampling and experiments, which can be conceived of as games of the observer against a malign "Nature" that is doing its best to fool the observer (the strategy).  Randomization ("shuffling") limits Nature's ability to do that.
